# Why can't I add User Scopes to my Slack App?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm developing a web app that is used by Slack community managers. We have our own interface and database etc that the manager interacts with in order to monitor progress in their slack community and to enact certain actions within the Slack community. The other Slack users will only interact with the slack bot part of our app.

I'm trying to set up some User Scopes but if I install anything other than the basic three required for OAuth (openid, email, profile) I get the following error:
[image: User scope error]

For example, I have tried adding channels:history, groups:history, im:history and mpim:history as required for the conversations.history API call, all fail in the same way. (I have also tried many others.) They can all be added to Bot Scopes but not User Scopes. Our app needs to act on behalf of the community manager at times, how do I resolve this? Is there a setting somewhere or a requirement that I've missed?

Apologies if this is a simple fix. I've searched online and can't find a solution. I only found one person asking a similar question with no solutions.

Comment: Have you added these scopes in the 'Oauth  & Permissions' section of your application?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm doing when it causes the error. I'm trying to add user scopes to the OAuth and permissions section of my application. When I do I get an orange alert at the top of the page that says I need to reinstall the app after making changes, I click to reinstall and I get the above error.

Comment: Can you try creating a fresh app and configure it from scratch?

Comment: If I can't figure out the issue then I can try that. If nothing else comes up I'll report back on whether that works